# PHP-SQL: How to ensure image details are not overwritten when updating only text fields

Tags: php, sql, image, forms, sql-update

I'm using the code below to update fields in my classics (books) database. The problem is that it fails to retain the earlier image, when I update only the text fields ie. it overwrites the image details fields with a blank (or something like a blank), so that what displays is the updated text fields but a broken image link.

```
if (!empty($_FILES["image2"]))

  {
    $ed_author   = get_post($conn, 'ed_author');
    $ed_title    = get_post($conn, 'ed_title');
    $ed_category = get_post($conn, 'ed_category');
    $ed_year     = get_post($conn, 'ed_year');
    $hid_isbn     = get_post($conn, 'hid_isbn');

    $filetmp = $_FILES["image2"]["tmp_name"];
    $filename = $_FILES["image2"]["name"];
    $filetype = $_FILES["image2"]["type"];
    $filepath = "images/".$filename;

    move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filepath);        

    $query    = "UPDATE classics SET author='$ed_author', title='$ed_title', type='$ed_category', year='$ed_year', filename='$filename', filepath='$filepath', filetype='$filetype'WHERE isbn='$hid_isbn'";     

    $result   = $conn->query($query);

    if (!$result) echo "EDIT with image failed: $query<br>" .
    $conn->error . "<br><br>";
    $result   = $conn->query($query);                   
  }
     else{
        $ed_author   = get_post($conn, 'ed_author');
        $ed_title    = get_post($conn, 'ed_title');
        $ed_category = get_post($conn, 'ed_category');
        $ed_year     = get_post($conn, 'ed_year');
        $hid_isbn     = get_post($conn, 'hid_isbn');
        $oldfilename = get_post($conn, 'oldfilename');
        $oldfilepath = get_post($conn, 'oldfilepath');
        $oldfiletype = get_post($conn, 'oldfiletype');      


    $query  = "UPDATE classics SET author='$ed_author', title='$ed_title', type='$ed_category', year='$ed_year', filename='$oldfilename', filepath='$oldfilepath', filetype='$oldfiletype' WHERE isbn='$hid_isbn'";     
        $result   = $conn->query($query);

    if (!$result) echo "EDIT with image failed: $query<br>" .
    $conn->error . "<br><br>";

     }
```

I know that the issue is that: when no new image is added, image2 never tests as empty and so still goes to the if block (!empty($_FILES["image2"]))` rather than the else. How then should I be checking image2 when no image has been picked? Would appreciate any advice.

Also, to be more complete, here is the form and attached is an image of a record with a broken image link after an update has been made without adding a new image:

```
 <form action="sqltest.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><pre>
        Author <input type="text" name="ed_author" value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>">
         Title <input type="text" name="ed_title" value="<?php echo $row[1]; ?>">
      Category <input type="text" name="ed_category" value="<?php echo $row[2]; ?>">
          Year <input type="text" name="ed_year" value="<?php echo $row[3]; ?>">
          ISBN <input type="text" name="hid_isbn" value="<?php echo $row[4]; ?>"readonly>

               <input type="hidden" name="oldfilename" value="<?php echo $row[6]; ?>">  
               <input type="hidden" name="oldfilepath" value="<?php echo $row[7]; ?>">
               <input type="hidden" name="oldfiletype" value="<?php echo $row[8]; ?>">

               <input type="file" name="image2">
               <input type="hidden" name="edit" value="yes">
               <input type="submit" name="btn2" value="SUBMIT EDIT">

        </pre></form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `$_FILES['image2']` is indeed always filled when the file input is submitted.

You can try the following:

1. Add a `var_dump($_FILES['image2'])` to the beginning of your script.
2. Send a request with no image selected
3. Save the output
4. Send a request WITH an image selected
5. Save the output
6. Notice the difference
7. Adjust your code accordingly

This will most likely lead you to the fact that you could for example check the `error` index of this field, like so:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['image2']) && $_FILES['image2']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) { ... }
```

However, you will probably have to restructure your code too, as all the other fields will not get updated when there is no image uploaded, if you would leave it as it is right now (because the if-block is never executed).

You can find more info about this here: [POST method uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) and here: [Upload errors explained](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: thanks that helped me get the array keys; I got ["error"]=> int(4), which i found is the same as UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE. However, when executing the new if, am ending up with the same issue as before, the older image is not retained when only text is updated.

Comment: Have you made sure that the right if/else is executed, e.g. by including some debug output? If so: I can not really see why it would do that, but I also don't have your full script or the full page output. I would however recommend to remove the `oldfilename`, `oldfilepath` and `oldfiletype` from the HTML, and subsequently remove the updating of `filename`, `filepath`  and `filetype`  in the query in your else part. The idea here: If nothing of your image was changed, then why update it at all? (This is all assuming that by "not retained" you mean the data vanishes from the database)

Comment: Thanks - that worked. Just by removing oldfilename, oldfilepath and oldfiletype & filename, filepath and filetype. So maybe oldfile name/path/type were not understandable values? Will try and figure. Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe they were empty in your HTML already, and there was the problem? I am sure you will find out! You're warmly welcome, happy to help :)